# Get email address from .eml file with PHP

Tags: php, laravel, email, parsing, eml

I have a number of `.eml` files, most of them are bounced notifications for not existing email addresses.

How can I get email address out of such files using PHP to know that this email does not exist and to avoid sending emails there second time.

Details:

The files are sitting on the `Amazon (AWS) S3` bucket and they are comming from `Amazone SES` service. Files don't have extension, but I believe they are in `.eml` format. I'd like to have them in my email.

My project is on `Laravel`, so If there is a way to do it in `laravel`, please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Show an example of such file (remove any sensitive data first).

Comment: please provide us one of your files to see the format of your data

Comment: https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no builtin way to parse the `.eml` files in laravel.

But you can read and parse the files yourself, and use a `preg_match` to detect the email addresses from the text, and strip them off from your email list.